# How to set cookie with predefined attributes

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript so i have a simple question, i want to set the cookie using JavaScript with the name=username , value=id and expiry date=30days. I have tried some examples but when i check cookie through my browser it shows
Name: Undefined
Content: Undefined
Expires: At the end of session

Answer (score 0):

One example is:

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
        ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires : "") +
        ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
        ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
        ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}

var expires = new Date(new Date().getTime()+30*24*60*60*1000).toGMTString();
setCookie("username", "id", expires);
```

Comment: Then the problem is in the variables you pass to cookie (i.e. `username` and `id`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in jquery world, you may want to check out the [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) - where you can just say:

$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });

And set parameters relatively painlessly.

When playing with cookies, it's important to remember the domain & path you're setting your query. It's probably safe to start with setting your query to path: '/' and domain: 'yourdomain.com' (so that it works on all subdomains).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var now = new Date();
var expire = new Date(now.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
document.cookie = 'username=id' + ';expires=' + expire.toGMTString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the root domain to make sure the cookie is accessible across subdomains (ex:  domain.com instead of www.domain.com).

Are you receiving the same result for all browsers or is this only an internet explorer issue?

I utilize these 2 functions frequently without issue:

```
function n__readCookie(n__name)
{
    var n__nameEQ = n__name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++)
    {
        var c = ca[i];

        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') 
        {  c = c.substring(1,c.length);  }

        if (c.indexOf(n__nameEQ) == 0) 
        {  return c.substring(n__nameEQ.length,c.length);  }
    }
    return false;
}

function n__createCookie(n__name, n__value, n__days, n__domain)
{
    if (n__days)
    {
        var n__date = new Date();
        n__date.setTime(n__date.getTime()+(n__days*24*60*60*1000));
        var n__expires = "; expires="+n__date.toGMTString();
    }
    else
    {
        var n__expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = n__name+"="+n__value+n__expires+"; path=/;domain=" + n__domain;
}
```